# Sql Server CE error when saving Winform?

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-ce

I have a winform app that uses Sql Server CE 3.5 and it has been working fine. I was playing around with deploying the Sql dl's with the app and wasn't able to get it working after much headache. I decide to just make the user intall Sql Server but now I'm getting this error. I'm almost certain I've reverted everything back to the way I had it. When I save the win-form in design mode, when it has the asterisk (in VS2010), I get this error and the asterisk won't go away.

[image]

Funnily enough I can debug the app, then build it and it works fine.

Comment: is the function async??